# What's the best way to visually convey rank?

Tags: design-patterns, info-visualisation, visual-design

I'm working on "infographic" style dashboard page where I want to convey the rank of something (and how big the whole group is).  So "Rank #17 out of 2,312" could be conveyed like:

[image: 1]

I'm not loving this visualization as higher/worse rankings result in a bigger slice of the "donut".  Is there an ideal way to convey rank that'd be an improvement over this?

Comment: What happens if you have a 17 out of 2,345,678? Doesn't look like much room there and it's already rather small.

Comment: What kind of rank? between how many possible? what is the assigned space? what kind of users/people will see that? is it a specialized community? Can you give more details?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the "best" way will depend on your needs and the overall style of the dashboard (what are users used to see - are there more similar visualizations?), but generally speaking, you can:

- Flip the semantics, i.e. worse rankings will result in a smaller slice.
- Simply use a meter bar instead of a donut.

Comment: +1 - A circle here to insinuate rank is very silly IMO. A circle has no beginning or end, so it is unclear from the glyph itself where the ranking falls. A linear graph I would think would be a better choice. You can fill up the meter bar just the same as a donut.